# Whether array consists of any value of another array

Tags: ruby

I have an array `a = ["1","2","3","6","7"]` and another array `b = ["2","4","7"]`. I want to check if any content of `b` exists in `a` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` operator of Ruby, it will return an array with `intersection` values of two arrays, below is an example.

```
pry(main)> a = ["1","2","3","6","7"]
=> ["1", "2", "3", "6", "7"]
pry(main)> b = ["2","4","7"]
=> ["2", "4", "7"]
pry(main)> a & b
=> ["2", "7"]
pry(main)> (a & b).empty?
=> false
```

In Rails, you can also use `blank?`

```
pry(main)> (a & b).blank?
=> false
```

Hope the above example helps

Comment: I guess `empty?` method would be better here since it comes from Ruby std library (`blank?` comes from `activesupport`), so it would be more general solution.

Comment: Yes @MarekLipka, I agree with you, `empty` can also be used, I will edit the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

that is so simple:

```
(a & b).blank?
```

actually what does it do is, it takes `intersection` of two array and returns the result then check if the result is blank/empty.

Comment: If the user seems to ask a simple question, he probably is not very experienced in Ruby. Therefore some explanation of your answer would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
a = ["1","2","3","6","7"]
b = ["2","4","7"]
b.any? { |e| a.include?(e) }
```

Comment: See my comment at G.B.'s answer